# Getting a scale of 1 in blender?

Tags: model, 3d, zooming, blender

Hello i have the following problem:

i want to import 3D models from a game and render them in 2D so they can be used in other games. (before someone is claiming it's illegal, thats wrong.)

for rendering the image i am using the open Gl rendering.
the problem i have is that i cant get the right scale to render the image. the only way to zoom in or out is using the mouse wheel. the problem is that i want to same scale for every model. when i import a small rubbish bin for example it's big as hell but when i import a whole map its way smaller which means i need to use the mouse wheel to get the right zoom. but there are no values which are showing the zoom scale. ( i am using openGL rendering)

how can i get the same zoom for every tile?
is there a way to get the zoom of 1 pixel of the texture= one pixel on the monitor?

hope someone can help :)

Answer (score 0):

3D models are not sized in pixels.
Note that in Blender you can simply type S0.5
or S0.1  (. or , ) depending on language settings
S stands for scaling after it press enter.